# SQL - find total records that occur before another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following schema and want to find the number of clients that have a typeId of 10 appearing first.  The answer with the following data would be 2 (client id 1000 and 1003 have a 10 on the 1st January and an 11 on 2nd January.

```
CREATE TABLE Event (ClientId int, TypeId int, Date smalldatetime)
INSERT Event (ClientId , TypeId, Date) VALUES (1000, 10, '1 JAN 12')
INSERT Event (ClientId , TypeId, Date) VALUES (1000, 11, '2 JAN 12')
INSERT Event (ClientId , TypeId, Date) VALUES (1001, 11, '1 JAN 12')
INSERT Event (ClientId , TypeId, Date) VALUES (1001, 10, '2 JAN 12')
INSERT Event (ClientId , TypeId, Date) VALUES (1002, 11, '1 JAN 12')
INSERT Event (ClientId , TypeId, Date) VALUES (1003, 10, '1 JAN 12')
INSERT Event (ClientId , TypeId, Date) VALUES (1003, 11, '2 JAN 12')
```

I have tried a few queries with ROW_NUMBER() but have got a bit lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM 
    (SELECT CLIENTID,TYPEID,MIN(DATE) AS DATE
     FROM EVENT
     GROUP BY CLIENTID, TYPEID)A
JOIN
    (SELECT CLIENTID,MIN(DATE) AS DATE
     FROM EVENT
     GROUP BY CLIENTID)B
 ON   B.CLIENTID=A.CLIENTID
 AND  B.DATE=A.DATE
 WHERE TYPEID=10
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1bf3d/1)

Comment: +1. Better than what I came up with. I can think of at least one scenario where my solution, depending on OP's requirements, might fail. *(what should be returned if there's only one record for a ClientID, TypeID)*

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following.

- self join the table on `ClientID`
- only when the `typeID` of the self joined table is larger
- and the `Date` of the self joined table is larger

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT e1.*
FROM   Event e1
       INNER JOIN Event e2 ON e2.ClientID = e1.ClientID
                              AND e2.TypeID > e1.TypeID
                              AND e2.Date > e1.Date
WHERE  e1.TypeID = 10
```

[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41c88/6)

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me record 1001 where the typeID 10 appears on Jan 2 and 11 appears Jan 1 so shouldn't appear. I may be able to tweak it though, hadn't thought about a self join.

Comment: @PaulMcCowat - that was related to the left outer join. I have changed it to an inner join to fix that error.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two row_number()s:

```
select count(*)
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by clientId order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by clientId, typeid order by date) as ct_seqnum
      from event e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1 and ct_seqnum = 1 and typeid = 10
```

This is doing an overall ordering and an ordering by type.  Your condition is equivalent to saying that both these are 1 on a row where the typeid is 10.

Comment: +1, thanks this was where I was heading.  I've used the other answer but this is very useful.